# Angular execute consecutive statements with delay

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have three lines in my code:

```
$scope.isActive21 = !$scope.isActive21;
$scope.isActive31 = !$scope.isActive31;
$scope.isActive11 = !$scope.isActive11;
```

I want execute first line then after 500 ms second and then again after 500 ms third. How Can I achieve this? I tried `$timeout`and putting these lines in another function called 'delay', but it looks like an overhead for such a simple thing, and essentially didn't work.

Plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/0y3pad?p=preview

```
$scope.delay = function(){

    var attempt=1

    if($scope.level==1 && $scope.round==2){
      $scope.isActive31 = !$scope.isActive31;
    }
    if($scope.level==1 && $scope.round==3){
      if(attempt==1){
        $scope.isActive31 = !$scope.isActive31;
        attempt++
        $timeout($scope.delay,500)
      }
      else if(attempt==2){
        $scope.isActive11 = !$scope.isActive11;
      }

    }
 }
```

And it is called from:

```
if($scope.level==1 && $scope.round==3){

    $scope.clickSequence=[]
    $scope.prompt=''
    $scope.congratulations=''
    $scope.failure=''

    $scope.message="Level 1 round 3 start"
    $scope.isActive21 = !$scope.isActive21;
    $timeout($scope.delay,500)
    // $scope.isActive31 = !$scope.isActive31;
    // $scope.isActive11 = !$scope.isActive11;

      $timeout($scope.finishRoundThree, 3000)

    }
```

What can I do?

Comment: well you need  timers so I don't see why you think using `$timeout` is extra overhead. Show what you tried

Comment: I updated my question with controller code, also a working plunkr. Plunkr do not seem to load preview though, I don't know why.

Comment: We don't need your full controller...only post what is relevant to the question/problem. If you have to you scale the whole issue down to a very simple demo that only displays this specific issue

Comment: plunker is useless , it throws error as soon as it loads

Comment: Updated plunkr link: http://plnkr.co/edit/0y3pad?p=preview

Comment: no idea what we should see in demo. Still has a mountain of code in it

Comment: Okay, the goal is to blink the buttons one after another at a specific interval. Blinking is handled by applying css class to the buttons, and intervals by $timeout. Till level 1 round 2 it works for two button. For three buttons I do not know how can I do. I agree it's mountain of code, any help to optimize it would be appreciated.

Comment: make a simple demo that only does just that. Not interested in wading through everything else in that code . See [mcve]

Comment: I removed most of the unnecessary code, whatever is left is needed to see the problem (actually one thing is being called from another). If it's still big, I would rephrase my question as: How can I have three button which will blink one after another at a specific interval i.e. 50ms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to rethink your strategy for this app because it's pretty unwieldy with all of your `isActive21` and `isActive32`, etc. variables. I threw together a quick little demo showing how to generate random blinking patterns that might get you started on a more maintainable path. Maybe you can use it for inspiration. Below is the code and [here is a working JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zun9rqtg/).

*css*

```
.box {
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 10px;
}
.green {
    background-color: green;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
.blue {
    background-color: blue;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
.red {
    background-color: red;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
.yellow {
    background-color: yellow;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
.lit {
    opacity: 1.0;
}
```

*html*

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
    <div class="box {{box.color}}" ng-repeat="box in boxes" ng-class="{'lit': box.isLit}"></div>
    <input type="number" ng-model="count">
    <button ng-click="start()">
        Start
    </button>
</div>
```

*js*

```
angular.module('app', [])
    .controller('ctrl', function($scope, $timeout) {
        $scope.boxes = [{
            isLit: false,
            color: 'green'
        }, {
            isLit: false,
            color: 'blue'
        }, {
            isLit: false,
            color: 'red'
        }, {
            isLit: false,
            color: 'yellow'
        }];
        $scope.count = 2;
        $scope.randomOrder = [];
        $scope.start = function() {
            $scope.randomOrder = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < $scope.count; i++) {
                var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
                $scope.randomOrder.push(randomNumber);
            }
            $timeout(function() {
                $scope.blink(0);
            }, 500);
        }
        $scope.blink = function(index) {
            if (index < $scope.count) {
                $scope.boxes[$scope.randomOrder[index]].isLit = true;
                $timeout(function() {
                    $scope.boxes[$scope.randomOrder[index]].isLit = false;
                    $timeout(function() {
                        $scope.blink(index + 1);
                    }, 500);
                }, 500);
            }
        }
    });
```